# Grails clean command giving error in Ubuntu docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, grails, gitlab

I am trying to run the Grails -clean command on Ubuntu machine running in Docker container but I am getting the below error:

```
$ grails clean

| Loading Grails 2.4.0
| Configuring classpath
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Required Grails build dependencies were not found. This is normally due to internet connectivity issues (such as a misconfigured proxy) or missing repositories in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy. Please verify your configuration to continue.
```

Because of this issue, I am not able to proceed further with the war file deployment using grails. I have checked the "BuildConfig.groovy" and added some repositories as well as mentioned in various portals, but no luck. Getting the same error again and again.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Akshat

Comment: Did you use --stacktrace to see the full trace?  Did you verify that your proxy settings are correct?  Please post your repositories section from BuildConfig.groovy as well, if you have done these things.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for your reply. Can you please let me know how to check the --stacktrace in the docker container? Also, please suggest how to verify the proxy settings of the Ubuntu system running inside container?

Comment: Run `grails clean --stacktrace` to see full output.  (You can also use --verbose; I don't recall if that will show you anything more helpful.)  As for the proxy settings: can you download other dependencies?

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your reply. Sure, I will check the stacktrace output. Regarding proxy settings, what exactly do you mean by downloading other dependencies? Please suggest!

Comment: Either you have a dependency that grails can't find, or your grails application can't communicate with the internet.  If you can get some dependencies but just not this particular one, it's a problem with this particular one.  If you can't get any, it's almost certainly a network issue.  There are many ways to configure proxies, and adding docker into the mix just gives you another one to figure out, but step 1 is determining whether that's even the issue.  The stacktrace should help.

Comment: Hi Daniel, below is the stacktrace output: grails clean --stacktrace
| Loading Grails 2.4.0 | Configuring classpath | Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1 
org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for xalan:serializer:jar at.... Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact xalan:serializer:pom:2.7.1 from/to grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): Connection to http://repo.grails.org refused

Comment: Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact xalan:serializer:pom:2.7.1 from/to grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): Connection to http://repo.grails.org refused
 at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43)
 at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
 at

Comment: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:127) org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1 Error Required Grails build dependencies were not found. This is normally due to internet connectivity issues (such as a misconfigured proxy) or missing repositories in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy.

Comment: Well repo.grails.org is up, so I'd say you probably have a proxy problem.  I personally don't know how to configure a docker proxy, but I imagine google does.  I'd start there and make sure that your docker container is configured properly.  Once it can reach the internet, update grails proxy settings to match.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the confirmation that it is a proxy issue. Can you please help me out how to proceed now ?

Comment: Are you using https for older versions of grails you need to start using https for the repo.grails.org.

Answer (score 0):

Try using https instead of just http.

```
    mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
    mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"
```

Also try running with Java 8 over Java 7 due to Java 8 default to TLS 1.2.

Comment: Hi Joe, I am using https only in the BuildConfig.groovy file to define the maven repositories. Can you please suggest me what else can I check ?

Comment: Try getting a bash shell in the Docker container and see if you can do a curl command to places outside the container.    docker exec -it <container> bash

Comment: Thanks for your reply Joe. Actually I am running it in Gitlab pipeline, so I think I will not be knowing the container ID to define it in the docker "exec" command in the pipeline job. Please suggest!

Comment: Try the build directly on the Gitlab pipleline server and see if that works first.

Comment: Can you clean build it on your own machine?  Delete your maven cache  if you build on your own machine.   C:\Users\youruserid\.m2

Comment: Hi Joe, the issue with grails dependencies is seen only when  I use gitlab pipeline and run it using the shared runner. On my local machine, I am able to run the grails clean command without any problem.

Comment: Did you delete the cache on your own machine?

Comment: No, I have not deleted cache on my local system before running the grails-clean.

Comment: Yes that is because it is already in your cache.  The grails clean command does not delete your local maven cache.

Comment: Okay Joe. So any suggestions how to resolve this issue with grails clean in a Gitlab CI/CD pipeline? Thanks!

Comment: What version of Java are you running in the container?  I recently ran into problems getting using Java 7 and grails plugins repository.